# Octopress app on Heroku shows only a Blank page

Tags: deployment, heroku, octopress

This is my first time using Octopress, although I've deployed multiple rails apps to heroku. Whatever I do, I unable to deploy my Octopress app to heroku. When I do, all I get is a blank page.

What I did was:

```
git clone git://github.com/imathis/octopress.git
cd octopress
bundle install
rake install
rake preview    # working on localhost
heroku create
git add .
git commit -m "yo"
git push heroku master
heroku open
```

But it always shows a blank page. I'm obviously missing something very stupid. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. You will need to push at least one blog post. Once you have your first post, your blog will come up instead of the blank page. When you add more posts and/or modify existing ones don't forget to use "rake generate" (like I forgot and then did not understand why the posts on Heroku don't update).

Comment: i have the same problem. i do have a few posts and they show up after "rake preview" .. tried re-creating the whole structure a few times, and created 3 separate heroku apps.. it always shows up blank. i am using octostrap3 theme.. maybe that's why ? http://kaworu.github.io/octopress/setup/install/

Comment: @SonicSoul do u solve it,I have the same issue. heroku logs always 404